# Power Query Conditional Average in Grouped Rows

Tags: conditional-statements, powerquery

I am using the "Group By" function in Power Query to average the values of several columns. I'd like one of the columns to calculate the average based on the entry in another column. The equivalent of the AVERAGEIF() function in Excel.

The relevant columns are [Condition] and [Net Close Price]. I am also using the List.FirstN command to grab only the 20 most recent values.

Here is what I am using to calculate an average for the entire column:

```
{"Avg Sale Price", each List.Average(List.FirstN([Net Close Price],20)), Currency.Type},
```

How can I edit this command so that it will only average the [Net Close Price] for rows where the [Condition] contains the word "Updated"?

I have gotten close by embedding the List.Select and Text.Contains commands into the List.Average command above, but I keep getting various errors. It seems that I'm not structuring the code correctly.

This is my most recent unsuccessful attempt:

```
{"Updated.Avg Sale Price", each List.Average(List.Select([Net Close Price], each _ (Text.Contains([Condition],"Updated")))), Int64.Type}
```

The error returned is "We cannot convert the value $599,000 to type function". I suspect I have my syntax all wrong.

Here is the previous step and my current code:

```
#"Filtered Close Date" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table Column1", each Date.IsInPreviousNMonths([Close Date], 12)),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Close Date", {"County", "Postal Code", "Condition"}, {
    {"Avg Sale Price", each List.Average(List.FirstN([Net Close Price],20)), Currency.Type}, 
    {"Updated.Avg Sale Price", each List.Average(List.Select([Net Close Price], each _(Text.Contains([Condition],"Updated")))), Int64.Type}
    
    }),
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample full code

```
let #"Filtered Close Date" = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Close Date", {"County", "Postal Code" }, {
   {"Updated Avg Sale Price", each 
     let #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(_, each Text.Contains([Condition], "Updated",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     in List.Average(List.FirstN(#"Filtered Rows"[Net Close Price],20)), Currency.Type}
  })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not able to get that code to work within the context of a Grouped Row. I added more details of my current code above.

Comment: Obviously I did try to use your code, and was unsuccessful. Thank you very much for your help.